# Adding instances of UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a webpage containing a panel and a button. When you click the button, I want to add a new instance of a UserControl to the panel.

The panel.Controls.Add method specifies that it adds an item to a collection.

I can do this using a local variable to store the number of instances of the control. Then when one it added it loops this many times creating new controls.

```
private void AddUCToUI(int counter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            MyControl ctrlMyControl = (MyControl)LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
            ctrlMyControl.SetID(i);
            myPanel.Controls.Add(ctrlMyControl);
        }
    }
```

BUT, I don't want to recreate all of the controls every time, as the user may have already entered data into them...

So all I want to do is create another control, and add it to the collection which already contains the first one.

```
private void AddUCToUI(int counter)
    {
        MyControl ctrlMyControl = (MyControl)LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
        ctrlMyControl.SetID(counter);
        myPanel.Controls.Add(ctrlMyControl);
    }
```

This should create a new control, give it an ID, then add it to the collection. However it seems to add a control in the first instance, then overwrite this control in the collection when I attempt to add another. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not calling the code with the same value for the counter variable multiple times?

Comment: are you sure you are on the same page? what happens if you _don't_ add any controls at all?

Comment: @Joon I increment the value for counter when the button is clicked. Even so, it should still add multiple controls with the same ID as ID is just a variable that I'm setting.

Comment: @Vlad The page begins with no controls. First click of the button adds one control. Second click replaces this control with a new one. It should surely be adding another one?

Comment: not sure if I'm missing something here.... whenever AddUCToUI is called doesn't LoadControl give you a fresh instance of MyControl.ascx? if so, do you need unique ID? and explicitly use setID? Sorry, if I sound dumb, I didn't work much with LoadControl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue:

Moving the code from `onInit` to `Page_Load` and using a session variable for `counter` solved the issue of incrementing it's value. Session variables are not reset when a PostBack happens.

Here is my solution:

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter;

    if (Session["counter"] == null)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        counter = (int)Session["counter"];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)  
    {  
        MyControl ctrlMyControl = (MyControl)LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");  
        ctrlMyControl.ID = String.Format("ctrl_{0}", myPanel.Controls.Count); //count = 0
        myPanel.Controls.Add(ctrlMyControl); //count = 1
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're adding controls dynamically, you will have to recreate them every time. However, if you assign the same ID to the controls when you recreate them, they will be repopulated from ViewState. If the controls are not being repopulated, you're probably recreating them too late in the page lifecycle. Try recreating them during `OnInit`:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)  
    {  
        MyControl ctrlMyControl = (MyControl)LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");  
        ctrlMyControl.ID = String.Format("ctrl_{0}", myPanel.Controls.Count); //count = 0
        myPanel.Controls.Add(ctrlMyControl); //count = 1
    }      
}
```

Another option is the `DynamicControlsPlaceHolder`. Essentially, this control takes care of the above for you, without requiring any additional code.

You can download it here:
http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the case. The SetID method is just one that I have created. It sets a local variable in MyControl. I don't think the ViewState will repopulate based on this variable as it doesn't identify this instance of the MyControl within the collection. How can I change this so that ViewState does repopulate it?

Comment: If you recreate the controls during `OnInit` and assign the same IDs to the controls it should get repopulated by ViewState.

Comment: Another option is to use the `DynamicControlsPlaceHolder` that I included in my answer. It's a really great control, and eliminates all of the work required to persist dynamic controls.

Comment: I've added the Oninit method, and a GetCounter method to make this work. The only problem that I'm having now is that whilst the OnInit method is running, counter doesn't seem to have a value?

Comment: Are you adding all of these controls to a container of some sort, like a `Panel` or `PlaceHolder`?

Comment: Yes, that line `myPanel.Controls.Add(ctrlMyControl);` is adding the controls to a Panel. I'm using a Hidden Field to hold the count. I'm watching the value for the Hidden Field and it is incremented every time the button is clicked, however whenever the OnInit method is running, the Hidden Field has a value of "".

Comment: Try using `myPanel.Controls.Count` for your counter instead The count will be incremented every time a control is added. I updated my answer to give you an example.

Comment: Just tried this. The `myPanel.Controls` collection is emptied every time `OnInit` is called aswell. This is why the loop adds them all every time rather than just adding the new control to the end.

Comment: Yes, that's how it should be. `OnInit` will be called every time the page is loaded. What matters is that the controls are assigned hte same ID every time the page gets reloaded, e.g. `ctrl_1`, `ctrl_2`, `ctrl_3`, etc.

Comment: But because of this, I can't use myPanel.Controls.Count for the loop, as there is nothing in it. It will work for setting the ID of the controls. But I need to get the loop to execute the correct number of times by replacing `counter` with something that will work here: `for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)`

Comment: I was using a Hidden Field to store the number of controls. I incremented it's value when the button was clicked. I need a counter that can be used within `OnInit` so that it knows how many controls to create.

Comment: Try moving the logic to `OnPreLoad` instead and see what happens.

Comment: This has the same effect. Quite frustrating. Is there another way to achieve this? Thanks for your persistence.

Comment: Try using the `DynamicControlsPlaceHolder`. You can use it like a PlaceHolder, and any controls you add to it will persist themselves.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work. I've posted my solution so you can see. I basically just needed a session variable for the counter so that it wasn't reset on `Postback`. 

The only issue that I am having now is that the `Page_Load` method executes before the `Button_click` method. So when you click the button the added control will not be seen on the page until the next time a `PostBack` occurs. Need to find a way of forcing a `PostBack` .